# Dynamically creating buttons in WPF xaml file/xaml.cs file after reading an xml file?

Tags: wpf, xml

I am new to WPF,

Problem Statement: I have a xml file that gives me the number of items that i need to create,
for each item, i need a button.
If there are 20 items---> on loading the xaml file,
the xml will be read, 
count(of number of items) will be read and created.

Is there a way to do this in xaml file?

Comment: Does the below answer fix your issue. Is there something else open that we could help?

Comment: @jacob aloysious..Thank you for the detailed explanation. This works but how will I bind each button to a common command(as the buttons are created at run time),

Lets say, I need to create a Tab in a tab control when one button is clicked, Is it possible to bind the button command to the viewmodel property which when fired creates a tab (the tabcontrol is not dynamic meaning I know that I can bind the command for my Tab to listen to the button click command )

Comment: Here is a similar example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35873/MVVM-Dynamic-Commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Here is a simple/quick fix:

Expose a Panel (say `StackPanel`) in the `Xaml` and add the new buttons to them as `Children` on run time...

***MainWindow.xaml:***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Loaded="Window_Loaded">

        <StackPanel x:Name="mainPanel"/>

</Window>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var buttonNames = new List<string>();

            // Parse the XML, Fill the list..
            // Note: You could do it the way you prefer, it is just a sample

            foreach (var buttonName in buttonNames)
            {
                //Create the button
                var newButton = new Button(){Name = buttonName};

                //Add it to the xaml/stackPanel
                this.mainPanel.Children.Add(newButton);    
            }
        }
```

## Solution using Data Binding

***MainWindow.xaml:***

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" >
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

***MainWindow.xaml.cs***

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        YourCollection = new List<Button>();

        // You could parse your XML and update the collection
        // Also implement INotifyPropertyChanged

        //Dummy Data for Demo 
        YourCollection.Add(new Button() { Height = 25, Width = 25 });
        YourCollection.Add(new Button() { Height = 25, Width = 25 });

        this.DataContext = this;

    }

    public List<Button> YourCollection { get; set; }
```

Comment: Your solution is far from optimal. I cannot write a solution now because I'm going to sleep. Will post the `correct` answer tomorrow.

Comment: This would be OK it it were some ancient archaic UI framework (such as winforms), but it's not.

Comment: @HighCore: Answer is it `wrong` or `Not Optimal`? Coz I see the user mention `I am new to WPF` .. Its possibly a hint to get a working version, and then try to get it optimized.. Please advice..

Comment: @HighCore: I have updated the answer using `DataBinding` and `ItemsControl`.. Is it close to optimal :)

Comment: A very nice solution.+1